# Looking for design info for a shaded pole for large contactor. Everything I find is for motors

Tags: relay

I have a large contactor with a shaded pole to prevent buzzing. The actual coil on one side is badly distorted and the other one is missing. I made two new ones as close as I could to the one I had, but they get over 500 deg in a few minutes. I don't know if the one I have is correct. The work well, no buzzing, but that is way too hot. Any practical design information would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your circuit specs ie. voltage, current, load characteristics? Possible to throw some photos up?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that shading coils are usually a single turn that often tightly fills the slot. You may need to fill the slot more completely. As mentioned in another answer, the shorting of the two ends should be welded rather than soldered. A solder connection may have too much resistance. The shading coil shown below appears to have been made by punching it out of a thick sheet of copper. That would eliminate the problem of not shorting the ends together well enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The term is SHADING COIL (or shading ring), not "shaded pole". That's why your hits are all coming back for motors, Shaded Pole is a type of AC motor.

Look at the total coil current and use wire rated for that current at least. the thing is, it MUST be continuous, the circle must be complete, which means brazing the ends, not soldering because the solder melts too easy.

Comment: By "total coil current", do you mean multiplying the actual current value by the number of turns in the primary coil? That would make sense, since the shading ring acts as a single-turn shorted secondary.